# Go to another navigation component using Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-navigation

I saw the new navigationview (I know I'm late to the party), so I want to go to another destination from the recyclerview adapter but I didn't understand how it exactly works. I looked around for a way to communicate with the NavController which is in the MainActivivty to go to another destination and I think the only way is to use a method in the mainactivity using ((MainActivity)context) way. I hope there's a better way to do it.

This is my first question ever so I'm so sorry in advance if my question is not clear.

Comment: the question is a bit unclear. Do you have a Fragment hosted on your Main Activity and you want to change Fragment using Navigation Component? Is that it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @HamzaMehboob yes but from the RecyclerView

Comment: You should define a click listener interface and add a callback from Recycler View to your activity. In your activity, you can navigate to any of your destination

Answer (score 0):

```
// in viewHolder method simply using context you can navigate to another activity.

recyclerViewItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but this will send them to an activity while I want to implement the Navigation Component, plus this one will send them to another activity if they click anywhere on the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a RecyclerView in NavigationView instead of menu, then you can make use of interface for onClick actions but i suggest that it's very improper to use RecyclerView inside NavigationView instead of menu if this is what you're saying.

> This is my first question ever so I'm so sorry in advance if my question is not clear.

You can try to show some images with description or you post some code next time